# Graph API subscription limitations with Microsoft Exchange

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-exchange

I'm working on an application for my organization using graph API. We're creating calendar events from our application. Now we want to receive notifications from Microsoft exchange if these calendar events are updated. So for that we tried using the graph API subscriptions. But these subs have a very small limit.

[image]

Source : [Azure AD resource limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks)

We have more than 2500 employees in single tenant and for those we'll need 2500 subs. So need help or a work around this limitation.

Regards
Thanks in advance
Tushar Gupta

Comment: The above documentation tell that it won't apply to calendar/events, just they're meant for Azure AD resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks) tell that it won't apply to calendar/events, just they're meant for Azure AD resources.